# How to handle a post request in JavaScript from Arduino ESP8266

Tags: javascript, express, post, server, arduino-esp8266

Hey StackOverFlow Community. I have just entered the world of JavaScript and Node.JS. But i know C# quite well. I'm trying to make an Arduino collect some data and send it to my Ubuntu server(rented at DigitalOcean). I'm using an ESP8266 Arduino to make a post request(Arduino wifi module), and i'm sure that that part works.

**The problem is, i want to recieve and display the data my Arduino sent on the server. But the JavaScript part does not seem to work (on the server).**

The ESP8266 uses a library here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino. Here is the code that the ESP8266 Arduino uses.

```
include Arduino.h
include ESP8266WiFi.h
include ESP8266WiFiMulti.h
include ESP8266HTTPClient.h

#define USE_SERIAL Serial
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

String ssid = "YourWifiName";
String password = "YourWifiPassword";
String website = "http://165.227.138.230/";
String data = "20";

void setup() {

USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
// USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);

USE_SERIAL.println();
USE_SERIAL.println();
USE_SERIAL.println();

for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    USE_SERIAL.flush();
    delay(1000);
}

WiFiMulti.addAP("drach", "a5b4c3d2e1");
}

void sendData(String data) {
HTTPClient http;
USE_SERIAL.print("Attempting upload to");
USE_SERIAL.println(website);
http.begin("http://165.227.138.230/" + data);
int code = http.POST("Doge");

USE_SERIAL.print("Response code = ");
USE_SERIAL.println(code);

if ( code > 0 ) { USE_SERIAL.println("Upload succeeded"); }
if ( code == 0 ) { USE_SERIAL.println("Upload failed"); }
http.end();
USE_SERIAL.println("HTTP.end");
}

void loop() {

USE_SERIAL.println("Waiting for connecting");
if((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
  sendData(data);
} else {
  USE_SERIAL.println("Connecting faled, trying again");
}

delay(5000);
}
```

The way we thought of handling the post request was with JavaScript using the Express and body-parser module. Express has an example on setting the Express module and a get request up. But there is no example of a post request. Link to express's example: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html. Here is the code we ended up with.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
console.log("Post triggered");
console.log(req.body);
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Our goal is to receive and log the data which the Arduino sent to our server.

We hope for a nice feedback!
Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The problem is, I want to receive and display the data my Arduino sent on the server. But the JavaScript part does not seem to work (on the server).